# How to stop browser(Chrome) crash on image load on window 32 bit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, crash, chromium

In image tag when base64 is set on image src attribute, then browser crashes,
- OS:- 32 bit Window .
- Version:- 6.1 (Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2)
- Chrome version :- 73.0.3683.103

### To get base64 text file execute following c# code in visual studio

```
 var bytImageData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileWithPath + ".png");
                    string strBase64ImageData = Convert.ToBase64String(bytImageData, 0, bytImageData.Length);
                    File.WriteAllText(fileWithPath + ".txt", strBase64ImageData);
```

### Javascript code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            load();           
        });

        var _imageByteStream;       
        function load() {
            $("#scream").attr("src", "");
            $("#performanceText").val($("#performanceText").val() + '\n' + "Before image load :" + window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize);

            $.ajax({

                url: "Content/Images/ImageStream" + $("#imageSize").val().replace('MB', '') + ".txt",
                dataType: "TEXT",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                async: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    _imageByteStream = response;
                }
            });

            $("#scream").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + _imageByteStream);
            $("#performanceText").val($("#performanceText").val() + '\n' + "After image load :" + window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize);
            _imageByteStream = null;
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="width:400px;height:300px;"><img id="scream" alt="The Scream" width="400" height="300" /></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="width:400px;height:300px;">
                        <textarea style="width:280px;height:300px;" id="performanceText"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select style="margin-top:10px;" id="imageSize">                      
                        <option>50MB</option>
                        <option>57MB</option>                      
                    </select>
                </td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button style="margin-top:10px;" onclick="load()">Load</button></td>                
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### How to reproduce :

1. Select 50 MB from dropdown. Click on load button.
2. Once image is rendered then select 57 MB from dropdown. Click on load button.
3. Repeat step 1 and 2 till browser crashes.
4. Most of the time 3-4 repetition browser crashes.

Comment: `async: false,`  might not make Chrome happy..